# Why won't my Arduino return its pings?

Tags: networking, arduino

I'm using the [SerialIP](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/SerialIP) library and am trying to make a SLIP connection for my Arduino. Right now, when I attempt to ping, the RX LED lights up, proving it did in fact receive the packet, but the TX pin never lights up, and the packet is not returned.

I'm using the example server program. It does manage to reach the main loop (already tested with some digital writes), so the only thing I can see that would be wrong with the code is IP address definition:

```
// Set the IP address we'll be using.  Make sure this doesn't conflict with
// any IP addresses or subnets on your LAN or you won't be able to connect to
// either the Arduino or your LAN...
IP_ADDR myIP = {192,168,5,2};
IP_ADDR subnet = {255,255,255,0};
```

I'm doing this through Ubuntu, and when I run `route`, I get this line:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
...             ...             ...             ...   ...    ...    ...
192.168.5.2     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 sl0
```

I thought maybe I had to change the subnet to {255,255,255,255}, but it still had the same result: a lit RX with no TX.

Now I'm left with no clue why this is not working. Why is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Arduino and Ethernet, but it appears to me that you have to program your Arduino to send back the ping. I am thinking that the hardware doesn't respond to pings automaticly. Post some code, or if your following a tutorial, post the link.

Good luck.

Comment: I followed this tutorial, and used the exact code that was in the example program:http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/SerialIP

Comment: @tyjkenn please tell us what you've tried. This is what Arduino says on the link you posted:     "If RX flashes but not TX, the Arduino is ignoring the packet. Ensure the IP address you assigned to the SLIP interface matches the one in the code uploaded to the Arduino. Ensure the code is running properly, for example by using digitalWrite() to turn a LED on and off in the main loop(). Insufficient memory can cause the Arduino to reset before reaching the main loop." Did you read that? I can't help you unless you give me more information. Good luck.

Comment: It reaches the main loop, and the ip addresses do match.

Comment: @tyjkenn I also found this: "These two addresses must not be in use elsewhere on your network or it will cause problems with packets being sent to the wrong place and getting lost." (On Arduino's website-arduino.cc) You should change your IP adress of your Arduino (and where you send your ping.) If it's already registered on your network, it will get lost (like it said above.) Try recopping the example source code\download it again to your computer and burn the sketch again. A line may have been cut off.

Comment: @tyjkenn Have you had other issues with serial communication before or with Arduino in general? It may be a manufacturing defect of your board or a cable. Try a different usb cable or reset your router and modem to give all new IP adresses to your devices (unless you have a static IP.) Some of this stuff is just ideas, but something is wrong... Try sending a ping from another computer than the Arduino is hooked to... Maybe even a Windows computer or check Ubuntu's website for how to ping it might vary on some linux distros.